# Whats the best practise on handling different access right to different inventory files in same ansible project?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

We have one ansible project for two teams with 3 inventory file:
inventory-all
inventory-teamA
inventory-teamB

TeamA has permissions for all and teamA, B for all and teamB. What is the best practise on handling this?
We use ansible-vault to encrypt those inventory files.

I assume it's currently not possible out of the box due to the limit of one password in ansible-vault, see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13243 .

Comment: Where does this project stored? In VSC like git/hg/svn or on some traditional storage like samba share or ftp? If VCS then which exactly? How do you manage access for existing teams? Please, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accompliushed by multiple Vault passwords which is currently not available, but on the roadmap for Ansible 2.4.

"Support for multiple vault passwords"

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/docs/docsite/rst/roadmap/ROADMAP_2_4.rst